# Terminology: what is the undirected graph underlying a directed graph called?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given a directed graph, suppose we replace each directed edge with an undirected edge between the same vertices. Is there a widely accepted name/notation for the resulting undirected graph? Thank you!

Comment: I've always heard it called as the undirected graph associated to the directed graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just saying "underlying graph" of the directed graph, as you have done, is the most common terminology. Add the words "undirected" only if you need to, for clarity or  emphasis. We don't often need to think about this - after all, if you're going to forget about edge orientations, why did we orient the edges in the first place?

You can find this term used when defining weakly connected digraphs. For example, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Digraph_connectivity):

> A directed graph is weakly connected (or just connected[10]) if the undirected **underlying graph** obtained by replacing all directed edges of the graph with undirected edges is a connected graph.

For another example of the usage, see the paper [The underlying graph of a line digraph](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(92)90156-5) by J.L. Villar. Well, I say "see the paper" but you don't need to click on the link to see the words being used :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not accepted terminology to call it "the disorientation of a directed graph".